# Clarification of netcat result

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, netcat

I've been trying to debug an issue on our servers and Im confused by this response from netcat. Can anyone explain why Im getting these 2 contradictory messages when checking to see if a port is working? Is it failing to connect via TCP and then succeeding with some other method (*)?

```
ubuntu@1-2-3-4:/var/log$ nc -vz localhost 7777
nc: connect to localhost port 7777 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to localhost 7777 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

IP4/6 results

```
nc -vz4 localhost 7777
Connection to localhost 7777 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
nc -vz6 localhost 7777
nc: connect to localhost port 7777 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: Could it be IPv6 vs IPv4, i.e. whatever it is on 7777 is listening exclusively on IPv6, not IPv4, and nc tries v4 first (connection refused), then tries + succeeds on v6.

Comment: You can check that by forcing nc to use IPv4 addresses only with `-4` option

Comment: That was it. If you want to make that the answer, Ill flag it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because your daemon is only listening on IPv4.

IPv6 is the default protocol, so if a given hostname has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, the IPv6 address is always tried first.

In your case, `localhost` has the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1` and the IPv6 address `::1`. But your daemon is only listening on `127.0.0.1`.

So, when `nc` tries to connect to `localhost` it first connects to `::1`, finds nothing is listening, and returns `Connection refused`. It then tries to connect to `127.0.0.1` and finds your daemon.